# What is Sansa being invited to?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the episode 'Beyond The Wall', Sansa receives a note from the maester that allegedly comes from King's Landing.

Sansa refuses to go to King's Landing (and the Lannisters) herself and sends Brienne of Tarth as her emissary.

Is it also Sansa who is invited or simply whoever is in charge of Winterfell at that time?

Comment: I don't have any evidence to prove it so i write as comment and not an answer, but i think it's the meeting where the wight will be shown to everyone

Comment: @Kepotx I have read that elsewhere too, but it seems weird for Jon to Invite Sansa to this because Sansa is already supporting him and he is ruler of the North anyway.

Comment: Do we know for sure who wrote the leter ? It could be a ruse from Cersei to unite both Starks in KL, for some reasons.

Comment: I see a close vote for being an "opinion based question". I don't see why this is opinion based.. she is invited to something so there is only 1 right answer..

Comment: only 1 right answer, that we don't know for sure. that why I commented and not answer : it is pure speculation. Maybe she is invited to the wight party, maybe it's a fake letter made by Littlefinger, maybe it's a trap made by Cersei... So all answer will be opinion based

Comment: @Vahx If the note came from King's Landing, presumably it came from Cersei. Sounds like she's trying to get all her enemies in one place again...

Comment: @Kepotx Just because there are different THEORIES does not mean there are different correct answers that are based on individual opinions. There were many theories about the shape of the globe, in the end, the correct answer is that it is round.

Comment: @vahx This has been put 'on-hold' in adherence with our current [Future Works](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5187/21267) policy, hence the 'Primarily opinion-based' reason. The answer will come out in due time, so wait until then.

Comment: @Vahx: Though I'm not arguing that this question should be closed, your globe analogy doesn't work. The question isn't just whether there is a single answer, it's also important whether it's possible to **currently** determine that single answer. E.g. "Will Jon die by the end of S08?" is a question that will have a single answer, but it cannot be answered **at this time**.

Comment: “We're going to a party. It's a birthday party. It's Sansa’s birthday party!
Happy birthday Sansa! We love you very, very, very, very, very, very, very much.” — Cersei Lannister xx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking two different questions here.

> What is Sansa being invited to?

The negotiation between Cersei and Daenerys, where the wight is shown. Proven by the fact that Brienne actually attends this meeting. There's no reason to think that someone could attend this meeting without having explicitly been invited to it.

> Is it also Sansa who is invited or simply whoever is in charge of Winterfell at that time?

The Starks have always been the Warden of the North, which is a fancy way of calling them the governor. Historically, all Northern houses are sworn to the Starks.

*To draw an analogy, before the events of season 7 the Tyrells would likely be invited to events to represent the Reach as a whole, without needing to invite the Tarlys (who are inherently sworn to the Tyrells). This makes sense, as it's pretty much the core idea of a feudal system, and it means you can have meetings without needing to invite [everyone and their mother](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/everyone_and_their_mother).*

It stands to reason that Sansa is invited to the meeting as she is the **official** representative of the North (i.e. recognized by the Iron Throne).
Sansa is of course backing Jon's claim as King in the North, but that's not relevant as to her invitation. Sansa is also still the governmentally appointed spokesperson for the region, which makes her presence relevant *regardless of her stance of the topic of Northern independence* (the meeting is about a truce between Danaerys and Cersei, not Northern independence).

Even though Jon is half Stark, his position of King in the North is unrelated to his Stark heritage (they could've made someone else King in the North and the story would be unchanged from Cersei's point of view). Cersei, representing the Iron Throne, does not recognize the King in the North, she treats them like a group of insurgents.

Jon's "insurgency" is sufficiently powerful to be relevant in the discussion of a truce (as is later evidenced by Cersei request to have Jon not swear allegiance to either queen for the duration of the truce), which means that Jon is invited for a different reason than Sansa.